error using ADODB.Command with parameters
I am trying to INSERT a record into a Microsoft SQL Server table using an ADODB.Command object, from VBA.
I never used it before so I may be making stupid mistakes.
This is my code:
Sub Test_Insert()
    Dim strMyQuery As String, Raspuns As Variant
    strMyQuery = "DECLARE @P01 nvarchar(100) DECLARE @P02 nvarchar(100) DECLARE @P05 char(4) DECLARE @P06 nvarchar(200) DECLARE @P07 nvarchar(35) DECLARE @P08 nvarchar(3) DECLARE @P09 nvarchar(20) " & vbCrLf & _
                 "INSERT INTO.[dbo].[ TESTE] ([Column1], [Column2], Activ, [Column5], [Column6], [Column7], " & _
                 "[Column8], [Column9]) VALUES (@P01, @P02, 1, @P05, @P06, @P07, @P08, @P09);"

    Dim oDB As ADODB.Connection: Set oDB = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oCM As ADODB.Command: Set oCM = New ADODB.Command
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    oDB.Open gcConn & "; Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS"
    If Not oDB.State = adStateOpen Then
        MsgBox "Without connection", vbCritical, "Error"
        GoTo Err_Execute
    End If
    
    With oCM
        .ActiveConnection = oDB
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .Prepared = True
        .NamedParameters = True
        .CommandText = strMyQuery
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P01", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100, P01)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P02", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 100, P02)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P05", adWChar, adParamInput, 4, P05)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P06", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 200, P06)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P07", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 35, P07)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P08", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 3, P08)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P09", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 20, P09)
        Set oRS = .Execute
    End With
End Sub

On this line
Set oRS = .Execute

SQL Server throws this error:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column Column1, table dbo.TESTE; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

In the watches window I see that object oCM (ADODB.Command) has correct parameters collection with all values not null.
Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?
I check if @P01 parameter has the right value in VBA. In watches window it appears that it is correct.

That is not valid SQL in strMyQuery. Please post your actual code.

What happens if you remove the DECLARE line from strMyQuery? If I remember right, you don't need to declare variables when you're adding them as parameters via .CreateParameter - I would expect you to get a "has already been declared" error but maybe in this scenario the net effect is it's re-initialized by your explicit DECLARE (in which case the value you pass via the parameter is dropped on the floor, after you saw it in your watch window).

@testing-ma-lady  If I remove Declare line I receive following error message:
Must declare the scalar variable "@P01".

Why is the error coming from dbo.TESTE but your code has a leading space in the table name (INSERT INTO.[dbo].[ TESTE]) -> is it possible that there are two tables, one with a leading space, and a trigger that inserts something into the one without the leading space? Also like @GSerg suggested, the code isn't valid, so I'm not sure how confident we should be that the code in your question is the code you're running.

I replaced the actual table name with TESTE and accidentally added a space as well. There is NO such space in VBA!

I tested the full query from strMyQuery in SSMStudio and it works perfectly.

Did you also accidentally add . after INSERT INTO, which isn't in VBA too? Please post your actual code.

It's definitely not from strMyQuery. The point in front of dbo remained when I deleted the database name. As I said, the SQL query works flawlessly in SSMS.

I made two changes and now it works:

I added in the first line of strMyQuery, after each variable " = ?;" (example: «DECLARATION @P01 nvarchar(100) = ?;»)
I removed the @ from the unnaming of the parameters (example: «.CreateParameter("P01"»


@Cip Should have removed the "@P01" completely.

Strange, it seems that NamedProperties does nothing

It was doing something, since the values ​​appeared correctly in the watches window, but they were going to SQL who knows what nonsense... If I have time on Monday, I will start Profiler on the SQL server, maybe I will understand better what happened.
A first hypothesis is that the main error factor was the lack of separator «;» and because of this SQL was interpreting first line wrongly. In SSMS I used one line for each DECLARE and that's probably why it worked.

Ok, i take it back, it's provider dependent. If you use the old hat Driver={SQL Server} it will replace ?, ? with your specified parameter names if using NamedParameters=True. Otherwise it will use @p1, @p2 etc. But it still only works with ? parameter placeholders, meaning you must use positional parameter style. If using OLEDB, it still to use @p1, @p2 regardless what you do, but still only ? placeholders are possible

So, the solution is, remove the declare thing, and change values(@p1, @p2...) to values(?, ? ...)
